# Adding current Date as new Date() in a string key in mongo db

Tags: json, string, mongodb, date, mongodate

I am trying yo add the below json to my mongo DB collection, The document has a field named value which is String.

```
"value" : "{\"name\"\"sample\":{\"maximumDate\":newDate(),\"is24hoursFormat\":true}}"
```

It is inserted correctly but when I run it, I don't get the date instead I get back new Date() as Text.
I want to have current date inserted into it.
Date should be always current, it is not static.

Can someone help me in this

Comment: How are you saying that it is inserted correctly.

Comment: @Gibbs, means no error came when I inserted the document, but I get returned new Date() instead of current date

Comment: manually in robot3t GUI

Comment: There is no insert command, I have just right clicked on Collection and added the document with the json mentioned

Comment: ok, did you use new Date() or newDate()

Comment: I used new Date()

Comment: But in the question, it is newDate()

Comment: I inserted with new Date() but after inserting it became newDate(). let me give a space and check again.

Comment: I have checked again, same thing is there with both.Not able to get current date

Comment: I only get back new Date() as text but not Date.

Comment: Why are you inserting that as a `String`? That's the issue

Comment: That is my use case. Is it not possible ?

Comment: You need to do string concatenation.

Comment: Can you pls tell me how